# If strings of matter are of the same substance how can matter carry differing charges?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, charge

Considering that a string is a loop of energy composed of the same underlying material how is it possible for it to be either positively or negatively charged? For that matter, how is it possible for it to be the same substance and to have zero charge?

Comment: Well, you could ask the same question of quarks I suppose. Charge is an attribute of a particular string.

Comment: @JonCuster: *Charge is an attribute of a particular string.* My knowledge of string theory is not far beyond the pop-sci level, but I thought string theory was supposed to produce the set of particles in the standard model without having those particles' properties put in by hand (modulo the landscape).

Comment: Short pop-science-ish answer is – strings vibrate in and wrap around extra dimensions. Low energy physics is described by effective field theories which in the presence of compactified extra dimensions resurrect the undead Kaluza-Klein. Check out what Wikipedia says on heterotic string theory and the string theory landscape.

Comment: @BenCrowell "string theory was supposed to produce the set of particles in the standard model" is very cute, especially in the light of the multiverse speculation :)

Comment: I accept that the masses of particles can be seen as a certain vibration or oscillation rate of a string but the question is about charges and how these can arise from the same underlying substance.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus: hence "(modulo the landscape)"

Answer (score -2):

The standard model of particle physics has these basic elementary particles

[image: elemaprt]

There is an equivalent table of antiparticles . Note that they come with charge mass and spin assigned. It is an experimental fact that has to be fitted in any mathematical models.

String theory models that want to describe elementary particle physics, must be able to embed this structure and the $\operatorname{SU}(3) \times \operatorname{SU}(2) \times \operatorname{U}(1)$ group structure which these particles obey. ( also any theory that aims at becoming a theory of everything).

The string is a generic string, and its excitations are the ones that have to map onto the particle table, and obey the group structure above.

So a specific particle is a specific excitation of the generic string, and the excitation level carries enough quantum numbers to accommodate all particles in the table, charges and spins and all.

In the standard model, each particle is represented by a point. The point may be considered generic on which the particles are labeled. When the standard model is embedded into a string model, the point becomes a string, that's all.

Edit after comment:

The misunderstanding comes here:

> Considering that a string is a loop of energy

It is not a loop of energy, a string is a mathematical locus of one dimension, of the same type that *a point*, in the standard model representation of particles, is a locus of zero dimensions.Both are used as representations of particles with a lot of quantum numbers and carrying a four vector describing the particles, with momentum , energy and invariant mass. These are assignments on geometrical loci. The point loci of the standard model have to be assigned on one to one representation to the group structure of the standard model, $\operatorname{SU}(3) \times \operatorname{SU}(2) \times \operatorname{U}(1)$ . String theories allow a structure on the vibrations which can accommodate the standard model group structure and thus are a candidate for a theory of everything, as they also allow for the existence of gravitons on their own vibrational level. That is the progress in theory.

Comment: Ok, but specifically, how does a vibration in a string produce a charge?

Comment: @SamCottle  The  vibration on a string does not produce the charge. The vibration's quantum numbers are  identified with the quantum numbers of the electron in the the embedded standard model, it is a representation. Charges and the quantum numbers are not optional. They are measured values fitted with the standard model.  The same as thinking the electron as a point particle. The point does not produce the charge, it is assigned a charge from measurement, and  is consistent with the mathematics of the standard model lagrangian . Another vibrational state will be identified wit the neutrino

Comment: and so on. All electrons will have that specific vibrational level on the string that identifies them, and all neutrinos another one that identifies them  etc